# How to get the Metadata of a Fungible Token using the Mint Account?

Tags: spl-token

I need to get the Metadata like name,symbol,image uri for a token with a mint address. what is the best way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import {
  Metadata,
  PROGRAM_ID as TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";

describe("metaplex", () => {
  const RPC_URL = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";
  const walletKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

  const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(
    new anchor.web3.Connection(RPC_URL),
    new anchor.Wallet(walletKeypair),
    { commitment: "confirmed" }
  );

  it("metadata", async () => {
    const mint = new anchor.web3.PublicKey(
      "FSz6W7vznZH2kvkjqYESk35NozQn6eScqwNduHc46wL1"
    );

    const [metadataPDA] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from("metadata"),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        mint.toBuffer(),
      ],
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    const accInfo = await provider.connection.getAccountInfo(metadataPDA);

    const metadata = Metadata.deserialize(accInfo.data, 0);

    console.log(metadata);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the token metadata was added using the Token Metadata Program, you can use the `findByMint` method from the Metaplex SDK, which returns an `Nft` object that contains all the relevant data for a specific token Mint.

Although its called the `Nft` model, it works for regular fungible tokens as well since metadata is associated with a token mint the same way.

```
  const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)

  const mintAddress = new PublicKey("TOKEN_MINT_HERE")

  const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress }).run()

  console.log(nft)
```

The metaplex docs are really well written with awesome diagrams, recommend looking through.

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/overview

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#findByMint

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#the-nft-model